# Prove that if $f(x)$ is measurable function then $h(x)=...$ is also measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, solution-verification

Prove:

If $f: ( X, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable function, $A \in \mathcal{A}$ then function $h:( X, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$h(x) =  \begin{cases} f(x) \quad x \in A \\ 0 \quad x \not\in A \end{cases} $$ is also measurable function.

$f$ is measurable function so $$\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \quad \left\{ x \in X : f(x) > a \right\} \in \mathcal{A} $$

Then I consider two cases:

1. for $x \in A$ 
   It is obviously, because we have $$\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \quad \left\{ x \in X : h(x) > a \right\}  = \left\{ x \in X : f(x) > a \right\} \in \mathcal{A} $$
2. for $ x \in X \setminus A$
   $$\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \quad \left\{ x \in X : h(x) > a \right\} =\left\{ x \in X \setminus A : a<0 \right\} = \begin{cases} X \setminus A \in \mathcal{A} \quad a<0 \\ \emptyset \in \mathcal{A} \quad a \ge0 \end{cases}$$

Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use that the product of two measurable functions is again measurable and note that $h=f\cdot \chi_{A}$ where $\chi_{A}$ is the indicator function of $A$.

Comment: Very, very nice :). But I would also know is my solution good?

Comment: I think you have the idea, but you have to "formalize" it: for example, you could write $\{h(x)>a\}=(\{h(x)>a\}\cap A)\cup (\{h(x)>a\}\setminus A)$ and then explain why the sets on the right hand are both measurable (that is in fact what you have said)